# How to put together different frequency tables (converting 9 columns into 8 rows and four factor levels as rows)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
dput(provasubset[1:4, ])
```

Which gives this output:

```
structure(list(Organismo = c("Nom1", "Nom2", 
"Nom3", "Nom4"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_org_plan = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_pressupostari = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_contractacio = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_serveis = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_ajudes_subven = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_info_electes = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
"Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_patrimoni = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor"), 
    compliment_perc_index_bloc_consultes = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
    "Entre un 50% i un 75%"), class = "factor"), compliment_perc_index_bloc_info_rell_jurid = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Menys del 25%", "Entre un 25% i un 50%", 
    "Entre un 50% i un 75%", "Més del 75%"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to put all the variables except "Organismo" as rows and in the columns get the sum of the values (the number of "Organismo" that correspond to each of the four levels) of each of the four  level options for each of the 8 variables

For instance

```
Name variable   Menys del 25  Entre un 25 i un 50  Entre un 50% i un 75  Més del 75%

Compliment(...)     3                   6                    5                6
Compliment(...)     2                   5                    8                5
Compliment(...)     1                   10                   2                7
```

I am getting different frequency tables as this

```
table(provasubset$compliment_perc_index_bloc_info_rell_jurid)
```

but I do not know to put them together in one unique table with the form specified above

Thank you very much!

Comment: `table(stack(type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE), -Organismo)[2:1])`

Comment: Thank you really much. Do you know how to change the order of the levels (columns)? (it should be: 'Menys del 25%',
                                                                 'Entre un 25% i un 50%',
                                                                 'Entre un 50% i un 75%',
                                                                 'Més del 75%')

Comment: you can index them directly ie `[, c(2,4,1,3)]` if you want the second, then fourth then 1st then third. I do not know how your data is. I just wrote that code and hope it works